# chrome.runtime.onStartup not running in Opera 23

Tags: opera-extension

Upon updating from Opera 22 (22.0.1471.70) to Opera 23 (23.0.1522.77) I found out that the event `chrome.runtime.onStartup` does not work anymore. The update broke one of my extensions.

Wrote a little tester extension to try it out, pops an alert if the event is run:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
    alert("StartTester: onStartup working!");
});
```

StartupTester:
[*link removed as answered*]

Try loading it in Opera 22 (if possible, if not try Chrome) and Opera 23.
The js alert did not come up in Opera 23. I'm very sure onStartup is supported in Opera 22 as my extension worked then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug. Thank you for the info - I've already reported that so it should be fixed in the next release.